# Artifactory returns HTTP 302 when accessing virtual repository URL

Tags: artifactory

I am facing a problem with Artifactory v3.9.5 resolving artifacts. I have the following setup:

- local repository called "gradle-snaphot" allowed for snapshots
- virtual repository called "repos" that includes "gradle-snapshot"
- an artifact X uploaded to "gradle-snapshot"

Now, when I try to get the artifact directly, it works fine (credantials passed but omitted here):

```
wget http://myrepo/artifactory/gradle-snapshot/x/SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml?trace
```

But when I try to get the artifact via the virtual repository, then it doesn't work:

```
wget http://myrepo/artifactory/repos/x/SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml?trace
```

wget output is:

```
Resolving myrepo... xx.xxx.xxx.xx
Connecting to myrepo|xx.xxx.xxx.xx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://myrepo/artifactory/repos/x/SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml/ [following]
--2015-12-11 11:17:18--  http://myrepo/artifactory/repos/x/SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml/
Reusing existing connection to myrepo:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-12-11 11:17:18 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Artifactory is just returning 302 moved temporarily to the same URL with a slash added like a directory notation. Any idea why accessing virtual repository is not possible this way? In consequence, my Gradle build cannot resolve this dependency.

Comment: Note that I can reproduce the odd behavior with a local repository that has only release artifacts (snapshots not allowed).

Comment: Which beats the statement you made in the original question "when I try to get the artifact directly, it works fine". Please clarify the question.

Comment: I don't see any contradiction. When i can access the local repository directly then it should be possible to access the artifact through the virtual repository that contains the local one.

Comment: You just said that you can reproduce it with local repository, which means it's not a problem with virtual.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich did you validate that when retrieving the artifact from the virtual repository it is being resolved from the correct local repository. You can do it using the trace query parameter (as seen in your wget examples)

Comment: @JBaruch My first comment was on a "local repository that has only release artifacts" in contrast to "local repository that has only snapshots" in the original question. Hope that clarifies. It was just a pointer to the fact that is not related to snapshots only but also to release artifacts.

Comment: @drorb Unfortunately, when accessing the virtual repository, the trace does not work, no content is in the HTTP response (I tried with curl and wget). Maybe the redirect and 404 prevents the trace. Can I see the trace in Artifactory logs or somewhere else?

Comment: @SteffenHarbich make sure you use the trace as described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval). It should not redirect. In addition, do you have any kind of proxy/load balancer in front of Artifactory?

Comment: @drorb I followed the documentation you mentioned. It is possible that there is some Apache proxy in front of Artifactory or that the Tomcat where artifactory runs in has some special configuration. I don't have access to all the infrastructure of my company, so I need to contact the infrastructure team first. But I found out something interesting for the problem: When I remove a remote repo from the the "repos" virtual repository then it works fine. The remote repo is configured as follows:

Comment: URL "http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2", repository layout "maven-2-default", list remote folder items, allow content browsing, eagerly fetch sources, some cache timeouts, my companies proxy, handles releases and snapshots

Comment: @JBaruch, I've just hit the same problem in 5.3.2. Can artifactory team detect this situations and provide some error message or something? Is there any issue about it?

Comment: @guai as Dror explained below, once we get `200`, our job is done. We have no way to guess that that's not what you asked for. The problem is with wrong redirects on ibiblio site, not with Artifactory.

Comment: @JBaruch, in my case its not ibiblio, its pentaho.org :) You could log some warning in case 3XX were received from remote repo so users have any clues what is going on. It was not really simple to find this post. I actually write my own question first and only then notice this one. And I spent about half a day trying different configurations. It would be much simpler if I read something like "jfyi there was redirects, they can cause troubles" in logs

Comment: That's a great feature request. Passing it on. Thanks, @guai

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is the remote repository pointing at http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2.
All requests to this repository will be redirected to http://maven.ibiblio.org/maven2/ no matter which path you are using and more important whether the requested resource exists.
The result is that when requesting an artifact from the virtual repository, at a certain point Artifactory will try to fetch the artifact from this remote repository and will get a 302 answer which redirects to the root of the repository. Artifactory assumes it got the resource it was looking for (got a 200 response code), however the returned resource is a folder and hence the additional / at the end of the URL.

The best solution would be just removing this remote repository and relying on [JCenter](https://jcenter.bintray.com).
If you do need it, use the http://maven.ibiblio.org/maven2/ URL which will save the redirects.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the URL and put that repo back in, without any problems. Nevertheless, I think this is a bug in Artifactory.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich the issues that once Artifactory gets a 200 response from the remote server it does know if this is the content you actually meant for or something else. It is possible to perform some heuristics based on the file name and type of repository, but in most cases this is not good enough.

Comment: Independent of the concrete problem that arises with a remote repo contained in a virtual repo, the virtual repo should continue to resolve and ignore the failing contained repos. This is what I see to be an error. Maybe this is already fixed in the 4.x but it was not easy to find out the reason for this behavior.

Comment: I agree that this should be considered a bug in artifactory and can confirm that it is still an issue for 4.3.2.