# Artifactory not resolving local snapshots

Tags: maven, artifactory

I'm trying to resolve SNAPSHOTS artifacts deployed on the local repository (`libs-snapshots-local`) but I'm having an unexpected behavior :

- when wgetting `my/group/artifact/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` artifactory redirects me to `my/group/artifact/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/` (same url with a slash added)
- then the subsequent request will fail with error 404

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Is this happening to anyone ?

#### UPDATE:

If I try to resolve the artifact using the `libs-snapshots-local` the download will succeeed but if I try with the virtual repository `repo` it will not work:

- `wget http://artifactory:8080/repo/my/group/artifact/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` = REDIRECT then 404
- `wget http://artifactory:8080/libs-snapshots-local/my/group/artifact/1.0-SNAPSHOT/artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` = OK

But the virtual repository `repo` should contains all the other repository by default (and I don't know if it is even possible to change this behavior).

Comment: What is the `<type>` of this dependency as specified in your pom? Is there anything that processes requests before they reach artifactory (for example nginx or apache) ? Since wgetting itself is not working, I am tempted to suggest that it's something in the way Artifactory (or something else) is handling request instead of a mvn or a pom problem. Would it be possible to look at the snippet of access log (`$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/access.log`) from Artifactory that corresponds to the wget request?

Comment: @Vartibolius which version of Artifactory are you using - version number, license type (OSS, Pro ...)?

Comment: Is is a plain bare artifactory 4.3.2 OSS installation (official docker image).

I'm getting this behaviour with `maven` and also simply using `wget` on the artifact url.

Comment: @Vartibolius please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221284/artifactory-returns-http-302-when-accessing-virtual-repository-url you might be suffering from a similar issue

Comment: @drorb That was the cause. Unfortunately I double clicked on the "upvote" thus undoing it for your helpfull comment. Please write an answer redirecting to the other question so that I can vote it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is related to a redirect performed by a remote Maven repository - http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2.
In some cases this redirect will cause Artifactory to assume it got a proper response from the remote repository while actually it is not the expected type of response (getting an HTML document with the repository listing instead of an artifact content).
For more details see the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221284/artifactory-returns-http-302-when-accessing-virtual-repository-url) question